# Appending to jquery autocomplete renderItem WITHOUT overwriting the renderItem

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

There are several posts regarding overwriting the renderItem of jquery's ui.autocomplete. What about simply appending to it?

My autocomplete search results are working great with this code - however my trouble is using the ._renderItem function blocks the selected result from appearing in the input tag.
Can someone help with the select function?

My code (in part):

```
$j('.searchInput').autocomplete({
        source: BASE_URL + "include/php/nocache/jquery_search_autocomplete.php",
        select: function(event, ui) {
            // move search term into input
            console.log(ui);
        }
}).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item )  {
            var li = $j( "<li class='autoli'></li>" );
            li.data( "item.autocomplete", item );
            if ( ( item.category_title )) {
                li.append( "<a>" + item.category_title + "</a>" )
                li.append( "<a>" + item.title + "</a>" )
                li.append( "<img class='autoimg' src='" + BASE_URL + 'images/category/tnails_75/' + item.category_id  + '.jpg' +  "' />" )
            }
            if ( ( item.search_phrase )) {
                li.append( "<a>" + item.search_phrase + "</a>" )
                li.append( "<a>" + item.title + "</a>" )
                li.append( "<img class='autoimg' src='" + BASE_URL + 'images/category/tnails_75/' + item.category_id  + '.jpg' +  "' />" )
            }
            if ( ( item.web_supplier_sku )) {
                li.append( "<a href='" + item.url +  "'>" + item.web_supplier_sku + "</a>" )
                li.append( "<a href='" + item.url +  "'>" + item.web_name + "</a>" )
                li.append( "<img class='autoimg' src='" + BASE_URL + 'images/sku/tnails_75/' + item.qm_sku  + '.jpg' +  "' />" )
            }
            li.appendTo( ul );
            return li;
};
```

Comment: What does the data returned by your PHP code look like (JSON encoded)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for _renderMenu? This allows you to create the menu all by yourself. But you still have to loop over each item to give it the data() attribute otherwise it won't work.

Here's mine:

```
var userTemplate = Handlebars.compile( $("#userItem").html() );

// ... later in the code: The renderMenu function...
_renderMenu: function(ul, items) {

 items.forEach(function(person) {
  ul.append(
    $( userTemplate({items: person}) ).data("ui-autocomplete-item", person)
  );
 });

 return ul;
}
```